# The JSON syntax vs html/xml tags

Tags: python, json

The JSON syntax definition say that
html/xml tags (like the `<script>...</script>` part) are not part of
valid json, see the description at http://json.org. 
A number of browsers and tools ignore these things silently, but python does
not.
I'd like to insert the javascript code (google analytics) to get info about the users using this service (place, browsers, OS ...).
What do you suggest to do?
I should solve the problem on [browser output][^1] or [python script][^2]?
thanks,

Antonio

[^1]: Browser output

```
<script>...</script>
[{"key": "value"}]
```

[^2]: python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2, urllib, json
url="http://.........."
params = {}
url  = url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params, doseq=True)
req = urllib2.Request(url)
headers = {'Accept':'application/json;text/json'}
for key, val in headers.items():
  req.add_header(key, val)
data = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print json.load(data)
```

Comment: Let me get this right. You have a Web service that returns JSON, but you'd like to track the users of your service?

Comment: Erm, create valid json would be the way to go? Seems silly to write a whole parsing script to try to wiggle it free from (x)html output, which can fail on a lot of different errors. However, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'browser output' (my browsers output is an image on my screen, or a HTTP request, depending on what side I'm on....

Comment: You can't put scripts inside JSON.  It's not HTML.  What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sound like two different kinds of services--one is a user-oriented web view of some data, with visualizations, formatting, etc., and one is a machine-oriented data service. I would keep these separate, and maybe build the user view as an extension to the data service.

Comment: Yes, I have a Web service that returns JSON, but I'd like to track the users of my service. At the same time, the users using python script to get json data complain about the JSON syntax. I'd like to fix the problem preferably from my service. Will it be possible?

Comment: Why can't you just track users on the server side? It really doesn't make sense to embed any non-JSON data in a JSON data service.

Comment: Track users on the server side is a good option but I prefer to exploit google analytics script.

Comment: Sure, but JSON isn't really meant for human consumption. Break out the JSON component into a pure data service, and build some client that consumes it. The client can have all the Javascript you want.